# Datomic insert blocks

Tags: schema, datomic

The Datomic Seattle examples use explicit ID numbers when doing inserts:

```
{:db/id #db/id[:db.part/user -1000014], :neighborhood/name "Belltown", :neighborhood/district #db/id[:db.part/user -1000013]}
{:community/category ["community council"], :community/orgtype :community.orgtype/community, :community/type :community.type/website, :db/id #db/id[:db.part/user -1000015], :community/name "All About Belltown", :community/url "http://www.belltown.org/", :community/neighborhood #db/id[:db.part/user -1000014]}
```

For ordinary inserts for a single schema - it is much simpler to generate the ID on the fly:

```
[
  {
    :db/id #db/id[:db.part/user],
    :car/model \"Ferrari\"
    :car/numberplate \"RENT ME!\"
  }
]
```

and this will generate the ID at the time of insert.

Suppose I have a more complex schema, where I want to represent a Renter, Car and RentEvent.

I could do:

```
[
  {
    :db/id #db/id[:db.part/user],
    :car/model \"Ferrari\"
    :car/numberplate \"RENT ME!\"
  }
]
```

=> get ID number and stick it in A

```
[
  {
    :db/id #db/id[:db.part/user],
    :renter/name \"John Smith\"
    :renter/socialsecuritynumber \"123456789\"
  }
]
```

=> get ID number and stick it in B

```
[
  {
    :db/id #db/id[:db.part/user],
    :rentevent/car A
    :rentevent/renter B
  }
]
```

But that involves lots of mucking around with ID numbers. I'd like to insert this in one big block, something like:

```
[
  {
    :db/id #db/id[:db.part/user],      
    :rentevent/car {
      :db/id #db/id[:db.part/user],
      :car/model \"Ferrari\"
      :car/numberplate \"RENT ME!\"
    },
    :rentevent/renter {
      :db/id #db/id[:db.part/user],
      :renter/name \"John Smith\"
      :renter/socialsecuritynumber \"123456789\"
    }
]
```

Is this possible? What is the syntax?

**Assumptions:**

- This is an auditable environment where a repeatable scripted database release is done to a production database by an party who is under separation of controls. Ie - this needs to be a text file that an auditor can look at before and after a change to the database is made.

Comment: you can isolate your application code from boilerplate/repetitive code through transaction functions as described below, is there something else you were looking for?

Comment: Yeah - I was looking for a way to handle the datomic IDs across entities when they're inserted from the datomic shell.

Comment: There's nothing different about the shell. You can still create the transaction function and use it, even if you are using the in-memory transactor. Note you have to transact the function **only once**, you can then use the `new-rentevent` function to **atomically** transact as many "rent events" as you want. There's probably no more concise syntax than `[:new-rentevent "Ferrari" "RENT ME!" "John Smith" "123456789"]]` as described below. Let me know if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible. Use a transaction function:

```
 ; create a constructor-like function
 (def new-rentevent
   (d/function '{:lang :clojure
                 :params [db cm cp rn rs]
                 :code [{:db/id #db/id[:db.part/user -1]
                         :car/model cm
                         :car/numberplate cp}
                        {:db/id #db/id[:db.part/user -2],
                         :renter/name rn
                         :renter/socialsecuritynumber rs}
                        {:db/id #db/id[:db.part/user]
                         :rentevent/car #db/id[:db.part/user -1]
                         :rentevent/renter #db/id[:db.part/user -2]}]}))

 ; transact the function so it can run inside the transactor
 (d/transact conn [{:db/id #db/id[:db.part/user]
                    :db/ident :new-rentevent
                    :db/fn new-rentevent}])

 ; make your application code use the transaction function instead
 (d/transact conn [[:new-rentevent "Ferrari" "RENT ME!" "John Smith" "123456789"]])
 (d/transact conn [[:new-rentevent "Jaguar" "AVAILABLE" "Kate Nash" "567894345"]])
 (d/transact conn [[:new-rentevent "Maserati" "PICK ME!" "Justin Williams" "789134353"]])
```

For the complete code sample, see this [gist](https://gist.github.com/a2ndrade/5235019). For more info see [Database Functions](http://docs.datomic.com/database-functions.html).

Comment: Sorry - I was assuming this was an audit-controlled production release environment (ie releasing to the database is a text script. ) Would you care to update your answer?